# JWT/OAuth token signature verification failed

Tags: php, .net, oauth-2.0, openssl, jwt

There is a .NET Framework-based Windows desktop application which communicates with a PHP-based backend web site. I am experiencing permanent signature validation failures when trying to validate the tokens provided by the .NET application to the PHP web site (`openssl_verify` returns `0`).

1. .NET Framework application uses a [Microsoft Authentication Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) (MSAL) to authenticate a user against an Azure Active Directory (AAD). The library returns a token as a string. The application sends this token as part of its request to the PHP-based server.

   var result = await Application.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes).ConfigureAwait(false);

   var token = result.AccessToken;

   headers.Add("X-Auth-AAD-Token", token);
2. The PHP-based server web site receives the token provided by the .NET application. It than tries to verify the token and use it when requesting user data from an Azure Active Directory. The PHP web site uses [Networg/oauth2-azure](https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure) library which is a provider of the generic [thephpleage/oauth2-client](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client) library which then uses a [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) library to handle JWT tokens.

The PHP application instantiates an `Azure` provider and calls

```
$provider->validateAccessToken($token);
```

where `$token` is the string received from the .NET application. This method calls

```
$keys = $this->getJwtVerificationKeys();
(array)JWT::decode($accessToken, $keys, ['RS256'])
```

where `$keys` are an array of public keys retrieved from the `https://login.windows.net/common/discovery/keys` endpoint.

The `JWT::decode` then split the token to a header, payload and a signature, decode them, choose the right public key and verify the signature:

```
public static function decode($jwt, $key, array $allowed_algs = array())
    $tks = explode('.', $jwt);
    list($headb64, $bodyb64, $cryptob64) = $tks;
    $header = static::jsonDecode(static::urlsafeB64Decode($headb64))
    $sig = static::urlsafeB64Decode($cryptob64);
    $key = $key[$header->kid];

    static::verify("$headb64.$bodyb64", $sig, $key, $header->alg);
```

where `jsonDecode` calls

```
$obj = json_decode($input, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

and `urlsafeB64Decode` looks like

```
public static function urlsafeB64Decode($input)
    $remainder = strlen($input) % 4;
    if ($remainder) {
        $padlen = 4 - $remainder;
        $input .= str_repeat('=', $padlen);
    }
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
```

The `verify` method then tries to verify the signature by calling `openssl_verify`.

```
private static function verify($msg, $signature, $key, $alg)
    list($function, $algorithm) = static::$supported_algs[$alg]; // list('openssl', 'SHA256')
    openssl_verify($msg, $signature, $key, $algorithm);
```

The [openssl_verify](https://secure.php.net/openssl_verify) function returns `0` which means that the signature verification failed (not match).

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Edit: I am not supposed to verify the signature unless the token is issued for "me". As the token I checked is scoped to a Graph API, only the Graph API is supposed to verify it. After I changed the scope of the token requested to the web application, the signature verifies as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In the `decode` function, the statement `$key = $key[$header->kid];` returns the key that corresponds to the `kid` header parameter you got from https://login.windows.net/common/discovery/keys.

As the keys provided at the url hereabove are under the JWK formt, this statement will return you something like:

```
{
"kty": "RSA",
"use": "sig",
"kid": "-sxMJMLCIDWMTPvZyJ6tx-CDxw0",
"x5t": "-sxMJMLCIDWMTPvZyJ6tx-CDxw0",
"n": "rxlPnqW6fNuCbdrhDEzwGJVux3iPvtt_8r-uHHIKa7C_b_ux5hewNMS91SgUPZOrsqb54uHj_7INWKqKEtFc4YP83Fhss_uO_mT97czENs4zWaSN9Eww_Fz36xq_uZ65750lHKwXQJ1A_pe-VOgNlPg8ECi7meQDJ05r838eu1jpKFjxkQrdRFTLgYtRQ7TxX-zzRyoRR8iqJc6Rvnijh19-YfWtBsCI1r127SFakUBrY_ZKsKyE9KNWUL7H65EyFRNgK80XfYvhQlGw3-Ajf28fi71wW-BypK1bTCArzwX7zgF3H6P1u8PKosSOSN_Q9-Qc9X-R_Y-3bOpOIiLOvw",
"e": "AQAB",
"x5c": [
"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"
]
}
```

OpenSSl cannot directly use a JWK. You must convert it into a PEM or DER public key file.
Hopefully, this key format is already included in the JWK itself: it is included in the first X.509 certificate in the `x5c` parameter.

You just have to

- Modify it a bit to get a valid X.509 certificate.

```php
$certificate = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----'.PHP_EOL;
$certificate .= chunk_split($key['x5c'][0], 64, PHP_EOL);
$certificate .= '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'.PHP_EOL;
```

- Get the public key from this certificate

```php
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($certificate);
```

- Use that public key with the `openssl_verify`function

```php
static::verify("$headb64.$bodyb64", $sig, $publicKey, $header->alg);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have played with this a bit and discovered, that `openssl_verify` accepts certificate as well, so in the current implementation of `openssl_verify` (even its not documented) is not required to extract the public key. I have no clue why nor I am in stance as to consider it as best practices, but passing a certificate or a public key is of no difference in my tests.

Comment: In the mean time I have recently learned that I am not supposed to verify the signature unless the token is issued for "me". As the token I checked is scoped to a Graph API, only the Graph API is supposed to verify it. After I changed the scope of the token requested to the scope of the web application, the signature verifies as expected.

Comment: I cannot say what is the best between the use of the certificate or extract the key. As the argument name is `key`, I prefer to deal with keys and not certificates.
`In the mean time I have recently learned that I am not supposed to verify the signature unless the token is issued for "me"`. For sure, if your application does not consume the token (e.g. it is just a proxy or repository), there is no need to parse it or verify it. If your application uses the claims (e.g. in an authentication context) then the verification of the header, claims and signature is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error until I included only my own custom scope in the scopes configuration.

**Didn't work:**

```
authRequest: {
    scopes: ['user.read', '[my client id]/[my scope name]']                   
}
```

**Worked:**

```
authRequest: {
    scopes: ['[my client id]/[my scope name]']                   
}
```

source: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609#issuecomment-300476662